# Is there any way to backup data in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Explain my sql backup without using dump

I want answer to my question

Comment: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/922687/how-to-backup-and-restore-mysql-without-mysqldump) or [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140219/is-there-a-way-to-backup-a-mysql-database-without-having-to-run-mysqldump) might help. But the thrust of these two articles suggests it's not a good idea.

Comment: For large databases, you can write your own scripts which SELECT INTO files that can later be LOADed back much faster than with a bunch of INSERT commands.